# Listview selection changed not working on touch device - windows 8 store app

Tags: listview, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

If I right click a list view item it fires selection changed, but if I try to do it with gesture it's not working it just scrolls the list down.  Is there a workaround?
I'm using C# and Xaml for Windows 8 store app.  Thanks.

```xml
<ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Margin="0,-10,0,0"
        Padding="10,0,0,60"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard80ItemTemplate}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        SelectionChanged="itemListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="7,7,0,0">
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: please post your xaml for the listview

Comment: done adding the xaml :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ListView, you need to change the swipe gesture setting to the following to enable touch selection:

```
IsSwipeEnabled="true"
```

You should also consider changing the selection mode to single or multiple, to allow an item to be selected:

```
SelectionMode="Single"
```